# Quartz string for a schedule which includes execution minute as well

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying to construct a quartz string for below schedule. Can some one help me in getting this done?

> for every 3 minutes between 9:15 to
>   23:59 during Monday to Friday

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tred Marko's suggestions, I've already created my own mechanism to parse these string and convert it into cron expression. I will send this to quartz whenever I find time

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with SimpleTrigger (every 3 minutes). You just need to restrict the time and day with an ICalendar. Adding a DailyCalendar (09:15-23:59) and a WeeklyCalendar (Mon-Fri) will give you needed exclusions (example times would be inverted of course).

You could also achieve this with CronTrigger if you'd use DailyCalendar to help restrict the hour range.